# Android Widget programmatically change remoteView settings

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there a list of all methods marked @RemotableViewMethod?
I am looking around but I did not find anything.
I need to manage an android widget remoteView and could be useful to know all the methods allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late in replying but I had a lot of trouble finding these too so I thought it's worth sharing for others:

[GrepCode -> Search usages of @RemoteViewMethod](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.1.1_r1@android%24view@RemotableViewMethod&type=type&k=u)